# How can I make vertical scroll bar for my div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site:

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=21

I want that when the resolution is automatically appear small vertical scroll bar so you can read the entire text.

There appears when you resize the window so my text,

http://i60.tinypic.com/2lmnon6.jpg

This is code HTML:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <p class="text-center">Hello World!</p>
  <p class="text-center">Am reprezentat şi am acordat consultanţă juridică pentru clienţi persoane fizice române şi străine, instituţii publice, persoane juridice române şi străine în următoarele domenii:</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="font-size:17px;color:white;">
<p class="text-left">Drept civil 
- agricultură, exploatări agricole, prelucrarea şi comercializarea produselor agricole; 
- comerţ cu produse alimentare; 
- imobiliar; 
- distribuţie de carburanţi; 
- transporturi; 
- asigurări; 
- producţie şi comercializare utilaje grele; 
- producţie structuri metalice; 
- design, fotografie, artă; 
</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="font-size:17px;color:white;">
<p class="text-left">Drept administrativ 
- producţie automatizări; 
- servicii de proiectare; 
- comercializare automatizări; 
- jocuri de noroc; 
- turism, hoteluri şi pensiuni; 
- medical; 
- construcţii civile şi industriale; 
- comercializare utilaje şi autovehicule, service auto; 
- producţie software, administrarea site-urilor; </p>

    </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="font-size:17px;color:white;">
 <p class="text-left"> 
- comerţ; 
- bursier, societăţi listate, investitori, fonduri de investiţii; 
- asistenţă şi îngrijire copii şi vârstnici; 
- exploatări forestiere şi prelucrarea lemnului; 
- extracţia şi prelucrarea minereurilor; 
- producţia şi comercializarea materialelor de construcţii; 
- instituţii publice; 
- instituţii religioase.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add overflow: auto; but unfortunately does not work or I added the line to be.
I need some advice from you so that we can solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add your css file in your question

Answer (score 1):

In order for `overflow: auto;` to produce scrollbars, you must first specify a height. Setting the height and overflow of .container-fluid at a media query breakpoint should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: have you tried this?
appears only scroll horizontally and vertically ... I want strange problem

Answer (score 0):

Overflow-y: scroll; 
The above mentioned style in your css should help achieve what you are after as long as you specify a height and width.